# ERROR: Publisher org.jenkinsci.plugins.discardbuild.DiscardBuildPublisher aborted due to exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Long story short - Jenkins 1.406 gave me an error for "Low disk space". I found out that the builds were stacking up, eventually filling up the disk space. I googled in order to find a smarter solution than manually removing older builds and I stumbled upon the "Discard Old Builds" plugin. It gave me the error in the title.

I tried downgrading the plugin and upgrading Jenkins to 1.504. Nothing seems to work, which is strange because https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16979 says that the issue is resolved.

Any help will be appreciated.